Understanding 旅行やゆーてえらいイキッとんなあ
An old man told a boy, who was excited for a field trip:

兄さん、旅行やゆーてえらいイキッとんなあ、まあ若いモンはそれくらいでええ

I am not certain about やゆーて and キッとん. I think they both correspond to だと言って and イキっているの. But what 旅行だと言って is supposed to mean? イキっているの means 調子に乗っているの, right?


Yes, やゆーて is roughly the same as だと言って. や is a copula in Kansai-ben. The basic meaning of 旅行だと言って is simply "saying (because) it's a trip", but you can forget the literal meaning of "say" and interpret it as "because (of)" here. A similar example:

何かが気に入らないといってすぐに辞めてはいけない。
You shouldn't quit immediately just because you don't like something.


It's true that, these days, イキる often has a negative connotation similar to 調子に乗る or "to act cocky". However, イキる in this sentence is simply a slangy way of saying 意気込む or "to be excited".



旅行やゆーてえらいイキッとんなあ
You're really pumped up (just) because of the trip

